# Find external site which sends 404 URL to my website

Tags: google-analytics, 404, spam, referrer

For almost an year I have been getting users to a particular page which does not exist in my website. This page for sure is not an internal link and my website runs on WordPress.

[image]

My site is almost spammed with users coming to these links. I'm unable to identify the source of these links.

For now I have added a htaccess redirect rule to redirect this path to the homepage.

**Things I tried:**

- Search google for the page `apmaserp/home1.aspx` but no search result of the same
- In Acquistion --> All traffic --> Referrals I found a website `apmas.lk` with similar name but this website does not exist
- Searched domain registry to find details of this domain, but domain does not exist.
- Verified Google search console --> Links to see the linking pages and no trace there either.
- Checked the web access logs of last 2 days and not even a keyword of the 404 URL.

[image]

**I need help to**

- Find out what is the source of these URLs
- Any thing I can do to stop these users from unnecessarily overloading my server causing downtime.
- When could such things happen ?

Is it possible that someone is misusing my Google analytics script and sending pageviews to the above URL ? Is that even possible ?

Comment: Over what time period are these 3,000-ish users coming? A properly configured server should be able to easily handle tens of thousands of requests per day or more, even on low-end hardware, without any concern of overloading the server or causing downtime.

Comment: Have you looked at GSC>Links to see if someone has created a link to you? Do you get the same (not set) when you look at the referrer via GA>Landing Page?  Sometimes those are different.  What about what country/city they come from?  Are these locations you can block with your firewall?

Comment: Do you have access log files that you can get from your webserver?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister The above report is for 7 days. There is no serious downtime. But I think it better to block/redirect even before it hits WP. Also though I can filter the URL in analytics these results spoil the collected data by adding more views and other metrics.

Comment: @Trebor I saw the "linked pages" and there is no link to the above URL. May be 404 URLs are not displayed there. Strange thing is even apmas .lk site is not seen in that list. https://i.snipboard.io/zbYyfv.jpg.

Is it possible that someone is using my analytics script and sending page view to that URL ?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I checked my web access logs of last two days and see no trace of the above URL.

Comment: If it isn't in your log files, it isn't hitting your server.  It is probably just a Google Analytics spammer that is pinging the GA tracker directly without ever visiting your site.  Spammers do this just to get their URL or keyword into you GA reports.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It does makes sense. I added hostname column and I see the pageview from a localhost - https://i.snipboard.io/WGsMPD.jpg I have added a hostname filter to exclude this IP ! Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.searchviu.com/en/spam-traffic-google-analytics/.  This is a good article on setting up GTM with additional parameters so that the only hits that show up in Analytics are genuine hits.

The process basically identifies "all hits that you control and exclude all other hits, that do not carry this identification" by adding an extra parameter to your Analytics preventing bots from spamming your account.